# I keep getting Quota violation error in PowerShell when changing Firewall rules

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, windows-firewall, windows-11, powershell-7.0

I want to change all Firewall rules to only apply to Public profile, so I tried this:

```
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule | select Name

$rules | ForEach-Object {Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $rules -Profile Public}
```

but i keep getting Quota violation errors like this:

```
Set-NetFirewallRule : Quota violation 
At line:3 char:26
+ ... s | ForEach-Object {Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $rules -Profile Public}
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [Set-NetFirewallRule], CimExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004106c,Set-NetFirewallRule
 
Set-NetFirewallRule : Quota violation 
At line:3 char:26
+ ... s | ForEach-Object {Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $rules -Profile Public}
```

how can I fix this? tried it in PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x too.

Comment: you read all rules and store them in the variable ```$rules```. then you do a loop but instead of assigning the single value to the parameter ```Name``` you passover all ($rules). so probaly you have to do: ```Get-NetFirewallRule | ForEach-Object {Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $_.name -Profile Public}```

Comment: @Toni Thank you, that worked! btw is there a way to make it faster? it took nearly 5 minutes to finish.

Comment: 5 min. is indeed a long time. how many rules ```(Get-NetFirewallRule).count``` do you have? if the goal is to apply rules only for the public profile you may disable the firewall for the domain profile....

Comment: I have 747 rules, needed to make them all public because i blocked connection on private and domain network as my VPN network adapter's location is set to public and I don't want programs use non-VPN connection. is it possible to make PowerShell process the rules in parallel ?

Comment: ok not a huge number... yes you can process items in parallel.... on PS5 .net Runspaces is the fastest technique I am aware of, but it requires some lines of code ;-) on PS7 you have ```foreach-object -parallel``` which looks much simpler to use than .NET Runspaces but until now I never used it ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, it is doing it much faster now :) can you post it as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, that you currently query all rules and store them in the variable called `$rules`. Then you loop through those rules but once you set the new rule you do not assign the single element of the variable `$rules` to the parameter `Name`, you assign them all. So a working version would be:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | ForEach-Object {Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $_.name -Profile Public}
```

As you said the processing is slow you want to process the items in parallel you may have a look at:

.net runspaces:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

or the built-in feature of PS7:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/